# Google Maps markers taking too long time to render with Info Bubble

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infobubble

I am facing a strange problem with infobubble utility of google maps

It is taking too long time to render markers when I am rendering markers with click event to shown infbubble window

Below is live URL

http://abl-web.com/abl/map.php

Below is the chunk of code that is causing problem

```
    function property_click_event(marker,image_url, sysid, address, price, city, bedroom, bathroom, sqft, type, realtor, mls, position){

        var property_content = getPropertyContent(image_url, sysid, address, price, city, bedroom, bathroom, sqft, type, realtor, mls);

        var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            content: property_content,
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 14,
            arrowSize: 20,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'white',
            hideCloseButton: false,
            arrowStyle: 2
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            if(lastOpenInfoWin) 
                lastOpenInfoWin.close();
            lastOpenInfoWin = infoBubble;
            infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            map.setCenter(position);
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        bounds.extend(position);
    }
```

The above function add attach click event on marker and property content to be shown on info bubble

Update: The problem seems to be there only on chrome

Thanks

Comment: What does `getPropertyContent()` perform behind?

Comment: It returns just html code, like html = '<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>';

Comment: Yes, I've just checked that code on your site. It seems that the part of code which you showed here is not cause of the problem because InfoBubble opens instantly. It takes a lot of time when you click on red marker with star. Does the same code handle it?

Comment: No, if i remove the code in this function it works perfectly with no delay, and on click of marker it is fetching properties data via ajax from a url and then display it, but that ajax time is normal only this chunk of code is causing problem

Comment: Not sure. It seems to me that `getProperties()` needs time to get all data, display map with new data... After that click on icon shows InfoBubble with info about prices, address... instantly.

Comment: Bingo I fixed the Problem

Comment: Could you describe the fix?